# using TfrxRect and GetRealBounds in a script

Tags: fastreport

i am tying to use the script

```
procedure BarCodeResize(Bc : TfrxBarCodeView);
var
r : TfrxRect;
begin
bc.Text := '1234567890 test 1234567890 asdf 1234567890';
r := bc.GetRealBounds;
bc.Zoom := bc.Width/(r.Right - r.Left);
frxReport1.ShowReport();
end;
```

but it shows me an error at line **'r : TfrxRect;'**

Comment: What is the error message? Thanks.

Comment: Unknown type tfrxrect

Comment: OK. Then where is your procedure declaration - in your form, or in your report code section? And how do you call this procedure? Thanks.

Comment: Report code section

Comment: In the onbeforeprint event

Comment: Thanks. It is really not late. I am using Tokyo 10.3 c++

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

If I understand your question correctly, you may consider the following:

- If you want to use a type, you need to call `AddType()` method of `TfsScript` class.
- In FastScript, only published methods of added classes are implemented. If you want to use public method (`GetRealBounds` for example), you need to use `AddMethod()` method of `TfsScript`.

The problem with your script (even if you add type `TfrxRect`) is, that `TfrxRect` is packed record, and FastScript do not support records. So, you may define your own `TfrxBarCodeView` class with appropriate methods.

Тхе example белов demonstrates one possible way to solve your problem (it uses Delphi, but I was able to reproduce and solve your error).

**Delphi part:**

```
unit FMainBarcode;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, frxClass, fs_iinterpreter, frxBarcode;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    frxReport1: TfrxReport;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TfrxMyBarCodeView = class(TfrxBarCodeView)
  public
     constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
     function GetRealBoundsRight: double;
     function GetRealBoundsLeft: double;
  end;

type
  TFunctions = class(TfsRTTIModule)
  private
    function CallMethod(Instance: TObject; ClassType: TClass; const MethodName: String; Caller: TfsMethodHelper): Variant;
  public
    constructor Create(AScript: TfsScript); override;
  end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   // Show report
   frxReport1.ShowReport;
end;

{ TMyfrxBarCodeView }
constructor TfrxMyBarCodeView.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

function TfrxMyBarCodeView.GetRealBoundsLeft: double;
begin
   Result := GetRealBounds.Left;
end;

function TfrxMyBarCodeView.GetRealBoundsRight: double;
begin
   Result := GetRealBounds.Right;
end;

{ TFunctions }
constructor TFunctions.Create(AScript: TfsScript);
begin
  inherited Create(AScript);
   // Add type
   AScript.AddType('TfrxRect', fvtVariant);
   // Add public method
   with AScript.FindClass('TfrxBarCodeView') do begin
      AddMethod('function GetRealBounds: TfrxRect', CallMethod);
   end{with};
   // Add class and public methods
   with AScript.AddClass(TfrxMyBarCodeView, 'TfrxBarCodeView') do begin
      AddMethod('function GetRealBoundsRight: double', CallMethod);
      AddMethod('function GetRealBoundsLeft: double', CallMethod);
   end{with};
end;

function TFunctions.CallMethod(Instance: TObject; ClassType: TClass; const MethodName: String; Caller: TfsMethodHelper): Variant;
begin
   Result := 0;
   if (ClassType = TfrxBarCodeView) and (MethodName = 'GETREALBOUNDS') then begin
      //Result := TfrxBarCodeView(Instance).GetRealBounds;
   end{if};
   if (ClassType = TfrxMyBarCodeView) and (MethodName = 'GETREALBOUNDSRIGHT') then begin
      Result := TfrxMyBarCodeView(Instance).GetRealBoundsRight;
   end{if};
   if (ClassType = TfrxMyBarCodeView) and (MethodName = 'GETREALBOUNDSLEFT') then begin
      Result := TfrxMyBarCodeView(Instance).GetRealBoundsLeft;
   end{if};
end;

initialization
  fsRTTIModules.Add(TFunctions);

end.
```

**Fast report code:**

```
procedure BarCodeResize(Bc : TfrxMyBarCodeView);
var
   R, L : double;
begin
   Bc.Text := '1234567890 test 1234567890 asdf 1234567890';
   R := Bc.GetRealBoundsRight * fr1CharX / fr01cm;
   L := Bc.GetRealBoundsLeft * fr1CharX / fr01cm;
   Bc.Zoom := Bc.Width / (R - L);
   ShowMessage('Right: ' + FloatToStr(R) + ', Left:  ' + FloatToStr(L));
end;   
  
procedure Page1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
   BarCodeResize(TfrxMyBarCodeView(BarCode1));                                
end;

begin

end.
```

**Notes:**

Tested with Delphi 7, FastReport 4.7, FastScript 1.7.